# get all folders in a files path in Applescript - so i can tag them

Tags: applescript, directory

I have a applescript that gets me a file object

I now want to walk through all of the folders above it in its path (each file could be many levels down) and tag them a colour.

So far I can see there is a path in file, but I dont know what type to cast it to (its not a string):

```
copy path of theFile as string to FileNamesPath
```

If I could get each folder, I could then apply a tag/label to make them a colour:

```
tell application "Finder" to set label index of theFolder to 3
```

How do I get each folder from the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the parent folder i use the container property.
For example we get for an file on the desktop:

> -> folder "Desktop" of folder "USERNAME" of folder "Users" of startup disk

To work with this output i change it to an alias:

> -> alias "Macintosh HD:Users:USERNAME:Desktop"

With a repeat loop i get all parent folders. To stop i you a stopFolder variable. In this case the user folder.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set stopFolder to POSIX path of the (path to the users folder)
    set labelFolder to (choose file) 
    set lastParentFolder to (container of labelFolder as alias)
    repeat
        if POSIX path of lastParentFolder = stopFolder then return "ready"
        label index of lastParentFolder # get label index
        set label index of lastParentFolder to 3 # set new label index
        set lastParentFolder to (container of lastParentFolder as alias)
    end repeat
end tell
```

The

> get label index

row is only to show the original label index in the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file or alias object with HFS path like this

`alias "Macintosh HD:Users:user:Images:1401711772700.jpg"` or

```
file "Macintosh HD:Users:user:Images:1401711772700.jpg"
```

you can try this little script

```
tell application "Finder"
    set labelfolder to (choose file) #or insert file object here
    repeat
        set labelfolder to container of labelfolder
        if labelfolder is startup disk then exit repeat
        try #labels are disabled on some folders
            set label index of labelfolder to 3
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
```